# grep and tabs: no match

Tags: linux, bash, grep

```
#cat sample
1   -1  2
2   2   2
2   1-1 3
```

I need to get all the lines that contains negative value, that is 1st line only. Values are tab-separated.
First I tried

```
# grep "\-1" sample
1   -1  2
2   1-1 3
```

But if I try

```
 grep "\t\-1" sample
```

I get nothing (no match). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825552/grep-a-tab-in-unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash, you can do this:

```
grep $'\t-1' sample
```

The `$''` causes escapes to be interpreted.

It's not necessary to escape the minus sign.

Comment: This reminds me: everyone should go and (re)read bash documentation every once in a while.  You sort of discover something that you didn't know before every time.

Comment: It works too, thank you. Unfortunatelly I can't mark more than 1 answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
grep -P '\t-1' sample
```

By the way, the sample you've provided is tab-indented. You may try the following for generic whitespace matching:

```
grep -P '\s-1' sample
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no facility for \t being tab in basic regular expressions (those described by `man 7 regex`).  As Georgi Hristozov pointed out, you can use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions to get this ability.  Some implementations of grep won't support -P, but other basic tools will have more rich regular expression languages, here are some examples which should work:

```
sed -n '/\t-/p' sample
awk '/\t-/' sample
perl -ne '/\t-/ && print' sample
```

In order to get it working with regular grep (without using pcre) you are going to have to put a literal tab expression in your regex.  In many shells where the tab key does something like completion, you can get a literal tab character with `Ctrl-v<tab>`.  so you'd type:

```
grep 'Ctrl-v<tab>-' sample
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `man 7 regex` for the POSIX regular expressions you can use, while `-P` for PCRE is supported in lots of places its not available everywhere (and the manualpage says its buggy so I don't always trust it myself) the POSIX ones should work in more places.

You can try something like this:

```
grep "^[[:digit:]]\+[[:space:]]\+-"
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line.
`[[:digit:]]\+` matches one or more digits.
`[[:space:]]\+` matches one or more whitespace characters.
`-` finally matches the negative value you were looking for.

Manual page for regex(7): http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex

*Optional solution*:

You can use awk to do this too (and certainly other tools). This is an awk example that prints lines where the second column is less than 0 (negative):

```
awk '{if ($2 < 0) print}'
```